# Meteor server side js compatibility

Tags: javascript, meteor

How do I achieve the same functionality on the **server side** that the **client/compatibility** folder provides on the client side.

I have files with lots of old js functions that are defined as:

`function functionName() {...}`

I need to access these from my new server side Meteor code but because they are in different files and Meteor gives each file its own namspace they aren't in scope.

I could force each library function to be global by changing the declaration to:

`functionName = function() {...}`

but this is impractical as I don't own or maintain the js functions.

To prevent this wrapping on the client side you can place the js file in the folder client/compatibility. How do I prevent this wrapping server side? server/compatibility doesn't seem to work. Neither does creating a package and using `api.export()`

Comment: Are you asking "how do I make a function global on the server"?

Comment: How do I make all the functions in a file global.I could edit each to use the `funcName = function() {...}` syntax but I don't want to change the files if I can help it.

Comment: If you don't want to modify the file, then you'll need to create a package and expose the necessary methods. The details of that process can vary depending on the input source. What lib are your trying to wrap?

Comment: I did try and create a package for the library file. However `api.export()` requires that the function is _"declared without var"_ but `function x(){}` is just shorthand for `var x = function x (){}` in JavaScript so it still doesn't work. This is the same issue I have with the unpackaged file.

Answer (score 0):

> By default meteor wraps each js file to give it it's own namespace.

That's not accurate. If you make a file `/client/lib/something.js` and put this in it:

```
GlobalObject = {};
```

Then `GlobalObject` will be accessible throughout the entire project.

Can you edit your question to be more specific? What are you trying to achieve exactly? Can you post some code?

Comment: It is still wrapped in it's own namespace even if you force the creation of a global object. I've updated my question as requested.